# script to preview two .png s side by side?

Tags: applescript, preview

I want to display A.png and B.png together, A left / B right or A top / B bottom.
I can of course

```
preview A.png
preview B.png
```

separately, then resize and move the two windows next to each other,
but that's a pain if you do it a lot.  Can it be scripted ?
If not, is there an opensource preview-like that can display side-by-side ?

(I have 10.8.3 .
[if-preview-app-in-os-x-is-not-applescriptable-why-does-this-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052816/if-preview-app-in-os-x-is-not-applescriptable-why-does-this-work)
on SO has a comment
"Preview does have an AppleScript dictionary by default in 10.9 but not in earlier versions of OS X."
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the two files with Preview, then run the following to position the windows:

```
tell application "Preview"
    activate
    set the bounds of the first window to {0, 0, 700, 1000}
    set the bounds of the second window to {700, 0, 1400, 1000}
end tell
```

Customise the coordinates as you wish depending on monitor resolution.
Syntax: {*x*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>2</sub>, *x*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>2</sub>}

Enable AppleScript in Preview in OS X ≤10.8 by quitting Preview and running:

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview NSAppleScriptEnabled -bool true
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in Automator as a Service. Using a **Open Images in Preview** Action and a **Run Applescript** Action.

So I could select the wo files and run the service on them.

[image]

The Applescript code should get the Size of the screen and set the bound of the windows accordingly.

```
set bnds to ""
tell application "Finder" to set bnds to (get bounds of window of desktop)

set FullWinWidth to (item 3 of bnds)
set halfWinWidth to (item 3 of bnds) / 2
set winHeight to (item 4 of bnds)

tell application "Preview"
    if (count of windows) > 1 then
        activate
        try
            set the bounds of the first window to {0, 0, halfWinWidth, winHeight}
            set the bounds of the second window to {halfWinWidth, 0, FullWinWidth, winHeight}
        end try
    end if
end tell
```

As grgarside points out you can run

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview NSAppleScriptEnabled -bool true
```

to make Preview.app scriptable for something like these simple commands.